# Sharepoint 2010, BCS and inner join

Tags: bcs

We have external content type based on a table in database. It was created using SharePoint designer.

Unfortunately one of the column is referencing another table, which is dictionary - primary table has numerical ID and another has this ID bound to text value, Status.

I wonder if it will work when I'll modify by hand query in BCS model adding INNER JOIN statement to retrieve text value of Status field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It actually did work. I modified query and updated field type to string, and works like a charm ;)